# How could you print the first for loop of nested for loops on one line?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to print a Tic-Tac-Toe board in the terminal, and give the user an option to choose how big the board should be.
This is my code:

```
sq = [["       ", "|"],
      ["   ", "1", "   ", "|",],
      ["       ", "|"],
      ["-------","|"]]

def square(board):
    for row in board:
        for slot in row:
            print(slot, end="")
        print()

number = int(input("How many squares do you want to board to be?\n"))

for x in range(number):
    square(sq)
```

The problem is that they don't print on one line. I want to print the rows and then columns. I tried adding `end=""` in the "for loop" but that didn't help.

Could somebody please explain to me what i need to change in my code in order to be able to print to the same row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: Thanks @MAK, but this doesn't help me, end="" also removes the newline, and it didn't help when i tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best way of doing this but

```
sq = [["       ", "|"],
      ["   ", "1", "   ", "|",],
      ["       ", "|"],
      ["-------","|"]]

def square(board, number):
    for row in board:
        for _ in range(number):
            for slot in row:
                print(slot, end="")
        print()


number = 5
for x in range(number):
    square(sq, number)
```

Will give you what you want.

You need to print *all* the required lines in the first line and then move on to the next line using `print()`. Once you go to the next line, you can't go back.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the slot loop and bring the x loop inside the row loop like this:

```
def square(board):
    for row in board:
        for x in range(number):
            print(''.join(row),end='')
        print()
```

Just add another x loop over the whole thing and you will have your tic tac toe board:

```
def square(board):
    for x in range(number):
        for row in board:
            for x in range(number):
                print(''.join(row),end='')
            print()
```